# Big Integer (String, 16)

Tags: java, hex

What does this line of code return

> String s = "059185556356";
>
> BigInteger b = new BigInteger(s,16)

What does the 16 do?

Answer (score 1):

As found [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger): The 16 means that the string will be interpreted as base-16, also called "[hexadecimal](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)".

Examples:

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("12",16)  // b == 0x12 == 18 in decimal
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("0A",16)  // b == 0x0A == 10 in decimal
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("10",16)  // b == 0x10 == 16 in decimal
```

Comment: If its interpreted as base 16, how is it converting into HEX ?